# Laravel - View [.site.Home.index] not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Fui abrir meu `localhost` hoje para continuar dando inicio ao meu projeto e me deparei com esse erro em todas as páginas que tento acessar, ontem antes de fechar as páginas estava funcionando.

Erro:

```
View [.site.Home.index] not found.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
Route::get('Contato', 'SiteController@Contato');
Route::get('Dicas', 'SiteController@Dicas');
```

sitecontroller:

```
public function Dicas(){

        session_start();
        return view('/site.Dicas.index') ;
    }
    public function Regulamento(){
        session_start();
        return view('/site.Regulamento.index') ;
    }
    public function Termos(){
        session_start();
        return view('site.Termos.index') ;
    }
    public function Tutorial(){
        session_start();
        return view('/site.Tutorial.index') ;
    }
```

Comment: Experimente usar o comando `Ctrl+Shift+F` e pesquisar por `site.Home.index`. Talvez você usava o arquivo e acabou deletando acidentalmente

Comment: sou novo no laravel aonde colocaria esse comando? @MatheusReis

Comment: Esqueci de citar que era pra fazer isso no `VSCode`. Ele tem a opção de pesquisar em todos os arquivos dentro de um `workspace`

Comment: @MatheusReis o site.Home.index existe e qual era o comando q era para executar? acho q vc editou

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+F`, ele localiza o texto, dentro de todos os seus arquivos

Comment: Não tem barra e mostre aonde está a view

Comment: Pra que chamar a Sessions assim tá errado

Comment: @MatheusReis coloquei e ele achou o ` site.Home.index` na minha pagina SiteController pois la que dou o `return view`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic ja tirei a barra e mesmo assim da o mesmo erro, e onte estava funcionando com a / normalmente, como se chama a session de maneira correta?

Comment: Tem bastante coisa fora do lugar a Sessions vai depender se precisa aí não tô vendo necessidade é preciso ver as pastas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo erro uma vez em um projeto o motivo era que sem querer tinha movido minha pasta `resources` para outro lugar verifique se sua Pasta `resources` esta na raiz da pasta do seu projeto

Comment: Obrigado, sem querer pelo visualcode Tinha trocado a pasta de lugar